# Как сделать чтобы первое выпадающий список меню закрывался при открытие другого

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помоги пожалуйста. Запутался и не знаю, как реализовать такую задачу: при клике выпадает список, при клике на другой список необходимо чтобы открытый список закрывался и открывался тот на который был клик.

Пример:
[jsfiddle-36sjz5g7](http://jsfiddle.net/36sjz5g7/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i = 0;
  $(".select_side").each(function(){
    i++;
    $(this).attr("data-name", "select"+i);
  });
  $("[data-name=" +i+"]").ready(function(){
    var thisAttr = $(this).find(".select").parent();
    $(this).find(".select").click(function(event){
      $(this).parent().toggleClass("opened");
    });
    $(document).on('click touchstart', function(e){
      if(!$(e.target).closest(thisAttr).length) {
        thisAttr.removeClass("opened");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 40px;
}

.select_side {
 display: inline-block;
 min-width: 196px;
 position: relative;
}

.select_side .select {
  border: 1px solid #000;
 position: relative;
 height: 39px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
 -moz-border-radius: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 0 47px 0 20px;
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    
}

.select_side .select span {
 font-size: 14px;
  color: #2F2F2F;
 line-height: 37px;
}

.select_side .drop {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 top: 49px;
 right: 0;
 background: #FFF;
 padding: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0 8px 25px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.06);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 25px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.06);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 25px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.06);
 border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 z-index: 200;
 transform: scale(0) translate3d(0,-40px,0);
 -webkit-transform: scale(0) translate3d(0,-40px,0);
 -moz-transform: scale(0) translate3d(0,-40px,0);
 -o-transform: scale(0) translate3d(0,-40px,0);
 -ms-transform: scale(0) translate3d(0,-40px,0);
 transform-origin: 50% 0;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
 -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
 opacity: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.3s ease; 
}

.select_side.opened .drop {
 transform: scale(1) translate3d(0,0,0);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1) translate3d(0,0,0);
 -moz-transform: scale(1) translate3d(0,0,0);
 -o-transform: scale(1) translate3d(0,0,0);
 -ms-transform: scale(1) translate3d(0,0,0);
 opacity: 1;
 visibility: visible;
}

.select_side .drop:after, .select_side .drop:before {
 bottom: 100%;
 right: 13px;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.select_side .drop:after {
 border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
 border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
 border-width: 7px;  
}

.select_side .drop:before {
 border-color: rgba(228, 228, 228, 0);
 border-bottom-color: #e4e4e4;
 border-width: 8px;
 margin-right: -1px;
}

.select_side .drop ul {
 display: block;
 max-height: 240px;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 border-top: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
 overflow-y: auto;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.select_side .drop ul li {
 display: block;
 font-size: 14px;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
 padding: 9px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.select_side .drop ul li:hover, .select_side .drop ul li.active {
 background: #F6F6F6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="select_side">
  <div class="select"><span>Выберите</span></div>
  <div class="drop">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="select_side">
  <div class="select"><span>Выберите 2</span></div>
  <div class="drop">
    <ul>
      <li>44</li>
      <li>55</li>
      <li>45</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).find(".select").click(function(event){
  $(".select").not(this).parent().removeClass("opened");
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("opened");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/36sjz5g7/1/

Comment: решение рабочее, но какое то адовое количество кода в фидле для такого простого действия...вот версия в 6 строк: http://jsfiddle.net/36sjz5g7/4/

Comment: @DenisMatafonov Вы убрали две трети функциональности - закрывание повторным кликом по той же кнопке, закрывание по клику на странице.

Comment: ok 10 строк: http://jsfiddle.net/36sjz5g7/15/
Не сочти за снобизм, просто хотелось сделать максимально коротко, без использования document.ready, обширных каких то функций. Это же тогглер простой.

Comment: @DenisMatafonov Я ж не спорю. Сам бы я тоже делал с использованием `$(document).on('click`.